Can you bypass/forward between M and F stages in pipeline to avoid control hazard?

My professor has presented the above pipeline diagram to illustrate how to deal with control hazards in a 5 stage pipelined processor by stalling after the decode stage of a branch instruction until the branch decision is known after the execute stage. However, I do not understand the arrow drawn between the M and F stages, which I think indicates a bypass, but I haven't heard of bypassing between the memory and fetch stages of a pipelined processor. Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Wouldn't you be better off asking your professor who presented the information to you in the first place?

@phuzi he has left on sabbatical and he isn't answering questions. There are no TAs to help either, as I am self studying this course from older lecture videos

I don't think that arrow goes between M(5) and F(5) — I see it as going between X(4) and F(5).
Nothing interesting happens in M(5) (bnez is neither load nor store) but it does in X(4) (bnez finally has access to up-to-date value for r3).
It is very hard to tell how branches are handled in the pipeline without more information as there are several variations.  But here even under variations the overriding problem is the Read After Write hazard caused by the write of r3 (addi) followed immediately by reading it with a conditional branch instruction.
Whether the branch test is implemented as early as early in D or as late as late in X it cannot know r3 until start of its X.  It looks like the branch is a taken branch, and that is implemented late in X, then (the taken-branch PC is) forwarded to F for the next cycle.
(The 3rd row starting at F(5) represents the code at targ being executed, of course, not the sw which would have fetched at F(3), but shown as C*.)
